# WSO2 Identity Server Basics - Making it Work

Tags: wso2

I'm new to the SSO world and I've recently installed WSO2 Identity Server 5.0 and done my best to hook in a service provider but I just can't seem to figure out how to make SSO happen.

Here is my current situation and goal:
I have a MojoPortal website where a user can log in.  From there, the user can click a link to our FTP site powered by GoAnywhere.  We want the user to be logged into the FTP site just by clicking the link instead of having to log in to it as well.  The FTP site is SAML2 enabled so I chose the WSO2 ID Server to give SSO capabality between my mojoPortal and goAnywhere sites.

Here is what I think needs to happen - sanity checks welcome:
1. User clicks to access the FTP website and my mojoPortal website needs to create a SAML request and send it to the ID server.  I can't seem to get a grip on doing this from an ASP.NET page.
2. ID server gets the request and validates it (you can test the request in the "SAML Request Validator" tool in the WSO2 console, right?)
3. ID server sends a response to the GoAnywhere FTP site which can be simulated with the SAML Response Builder tool in the ID server console.
4. The FTP sites says either OK or NO to access.
5. Not sure what happens next - how does the user get redirected to the FTP site.

So I have big issues: I don't understand the flow in great enough detail and I'm also having difficulties in getting the technologies to work together.

Any comments / help at all are greatly apprciated!

Answer (score 0):

MojoPortal website - is this SAML2 Web Browser based SSO supported? If yes, then the solutions is clear.

You just have to register your 2 sites in WSO2 IS as SPs.

Then what will happen is , once the user log-in to the MojoPortal website, he user will have a live login session, therefore once he clicks on the FTP site, he will be able to access it without having to log-in again.

Hope this clarifies your doubts.